# What happens when a MySQL table gets REALLY big?

Tags: mysql, size, limit

I'm working on a project and I'm concerned about size limitations of a table.
If a table gets too big for the max file size of the OS. Windows is 2GB per file.

Does MySQL split the data from the table into two files?

I was looking at the data from my WAMP installation and right now each table is a single file:
user.frm and user.ibd (this one is the one storing all the data according to the file size)

Basically if I'm looking at data in the size of 10-50GB stored in one table can the MySQL database handle it?

**EDIT:** Also I'm eventually moving my project to a Linux server with the same file size limitations I'm assuming MySQL works the same way on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Planets get mildly nudged from their orbits. No biggie. Aside from that, have you looked at partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Limits on Table Size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html), the table size is limited by the maximum file size, but the maximum file size depends on the file system.

Make sure you put your data on a modern file system, such as NTFS, and you wont have any problems.

Comment: Perfect link! I found what I was looking for on that page: "The InnoDB storage engine maintains InnoDB tables within a tablespace that can be created from several files. This enables a table to exceed the maximum individual file size. The tablespace can include raw disk partitions, which permits extremely large tables. The maximum tablespace size is 64TB."